# inet_addr function and leading zeros

Tags: c++, network-protocols

I'm trying to use the `inet_addr` function to convert a char IP address, but I think since the IP Address i'm passing in to the 'inet_addr' function has leading zero's `(192.169.055.075)`, the 'inet_addr' function is interpreting this differently. Any suggestion on how to remove the leading zeros?

Thanks

```
char IPAddr[20]; //192.169.055.075
ulAddr = inet_addr(IPAddr);
```

Comment: inet_addr() interprets the octets with leading zeroes as octal.  http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/inet_addr.html

Comment: Fred you should promote that to a true answer :)

Comment: @Doug, I didn't think it really answered the question, since it doesn't say anything about what to do about it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `inet_pton(3)` instead - it doesn't interpret leading zero as octal prefix.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
string addr("192.168.055.075");
replace( addr.begin(), addr.end(), '.', ' ' );
istringstream iss(addr);
int a,b,c,d; 
iss >> a >> b >> c >> d;
ostringstream oss; 
oss << a << '.' << b << '.' << c << '.' << d;
string addrWithoutLeadingZeros( oss.str() );
```

Comment: Thank you....Here is also another way found to solve the problem I had.


int a[4];

char c[20];
  
if ( sscanf("192.169.055.075","%03d.%03d.%03d.%03d", a,a+1,a+2,a+3)== 4)

{
    sprintf(c, "%d.%d.%d.%d", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
  
}